# jQuery if "this" contains

Tags: jquery, this, contains

I'm trying to change any elements containing a particular text string to a red color. In my example I can get the child elements to become blue, but there's something about the way I've written the 'Replace Me' line that is incorrect; the red color change doesn't happen. I note that the "contains" method is usually written as `:contains` but I couldn't get that to validate with `$(this)`.

```
$('#main-content-panel .entry').each(function() {
       $(this).css('color', 'blue');      
});         

$('#main-content-panel .entry').each(function() {
   if($(this).contains("Replace Me").length > 0) {
        $(this).css('color', 'red'); 
    }      
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zatHH/

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`:contains` is a selector. To check if a selector applies to given variable, you can use [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
if($(this).is(':contains("Replace Me")'))
```

However Vega's solution is cleaner in this case.

Comment: This is perfect for conditional statement processing.  Thanks

Comment: Works splendidly when using a jquery variable, such as `$bodyText = $('div.bodyText ul li p');` Then it can be use as `if($bodyText.is(':contains("some text")'))` . Appreciate it.

Comment: I needed this, but when I read `If this is contains`, it sounds like the stupidest English possible :)

Answer (score 18):

<s>I don't think there is a `.contains` function in jQuery.</s> There is a `.contains` function but that function is used to see if a DOM element is a descendant of another DOM element. [See documentation for .contains.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)  (Credits to [@beezir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1973612/beezir))

I think you are looking for `:contains` selector. See below for more details,

```
$('#main-content-panel .entry:contains("Replace Me")').css('color', 'red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zatHH/1/

Answer (score 15):

you can use `match` to find the text inside the particular element

```js
$('#main-content-panel .entry').each(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'blue');      
});   

$('#main-content-panel .entry').each(function() {
    if($(this).text().match('Replace Me')) {
        $(this).css('color', 'red'); 
    }      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-content-panel">
    <div class="entry">ABC</div>
    <div class="entry">ABC Replace Me</div>
    <div class="entry">ABC</div>
    <div class="entry">ABC Replace Me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped me.  Similar to VB.net ".contains()"

Comment: Works but case insensitive

Answer (score 7):

I think we should convert our text to lower case. It is better to check with lowercase and uppercase.

```
$('#main-content-panel .entry').each(function() {
    var ourText = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); // convert text to Lowercase
    if(ourText.match('replace me')) {
        $(this).css('color', 'red'); 
    }      
});
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Was trying to get match work earlier with a variable, and this helped me out. thank you.