# checking a element's content on mouse enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set a mouse enter event that triggers if the element contains a certain text, but it's not recognizing the :contains parameter for some reason.

html:

```
<div class="sample">red</div>
<div class="sample">text</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(".sample").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
    if($("this:contains('red')").length > 0)
   { $(this).css("background-color","red")}
    },

    mouseleave: function () {
     if($("this:contains('red')").length > 0){
        $(this).css("background-color","yellow")}
    }
});
```

[This is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/silverstarfy/cgWdF/191/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/14510323

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd check the value of the `.text()` of the `div`.  Your selector is off, since you're not selecting the JS `this`, but the string 'this'.

```js
$(".sample").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
    if($(this).text() =='Red') { 
      $(this).css("background-color","red")}
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sample">Red</div>
<div class="sample">Text</div>
```

Comment: `$(this+":contains('red')")` is wrong anyway. see my comment on that answer.

Comment: @BenG Ha!  Thanks, edited mine to remove the reference.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
$(".sample").on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    if ($(this).is(":contains('red')")) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "red")
  }
},
mouseleave: function() {
    if ($(this).is(":contains('red')")) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "yellow")
   }
  }
});
```

'This' should not be in quotes

Comment: this is wrong. check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgWdF/193/). it changes color for both. put a debugger in for `$(this+":contains('red')")` and it brings back about 5 elements, include `<script>`

Comment: @BenG You are right, edited my code with a working answer

Comment: so... basically copied mine.

Comment: @BenG I didn't check honestly.

Answer (score 1):

use `is`:-

```js
$(".sample").on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    if ($(this).is(":contains('red')")) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "red")
    }
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    if ($(this).is(":contains('red')")) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "yellow")
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sample">red</div>
<div class="sample">text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery .text()

```
$(".sample").on({
mouseenter: function () {
if($(this).text()=="red")
{ 
  $(this).css("background-color","red")}
},

mouseleave: function () {
 if($(this).text()=="red"){
    $(this).css("background-color","yellow")}
}
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the complicated:

```
if($("this:contains('red')").length > 0)
```

try instead the simpler:

```
if(this.innerHTML === 'red')
```

It works fine. You can also use:

```
if(this.textContent === 'red')
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested this way of doing it and it works.

I'm not sure how to get the contains to work within that sort of statement - i have a feeling it is to do with that you are checking the element and not it's text, try using this instead:

```
$(function(){
$(".sample").on({
  mouseenter: function () {
    if(this.innerHTML.indexOf("red") != -1){
       $(this).css("background-color","red")
     }
  },

  mouseleave: function () {
    if(this.innerHTML.indexOf("red") != -1){
      $(this).css("background-color","yellow")
    }
  }
});
```